# How to test app downloads and activation?

Tags: android, ios, app-store

My team has recently built an app. At this stage, we're looking into expanding our app users by giving incentives to our team members who will be positioned at booths in malls. Their job is to get people to download our apps and test it.

Before that could happen, I need to test it so no spoofing happens. Our verification system will "pass" a user if these criteria is met;

- Activation via email.
- Connecting your credit card and activating it.

How can i test if this is working? I can simply create a new email account for testing purposes but how can i use a credit card generator to test if this works? Do note that credit card company will send a SMS TAC. How do I bypass this and get the account activated?

Note: This is for internal testing purposes only. Since the app isn't live yet, no purchases can be done. I will only input my real card data once the app is live.